# Can my sister open a Coverdell ESA for my son?

Tags: united-states, savings, education-savings, coverdell-esa

My son is, naturally, claimed as a dependent on my tax returns. My question is:

*Can my sister open a Coverdell Education Savings Account (an education IRA) for my son (her nephew)?*

I am aware that this presents no tax benefit at the time of contribution, but given that the growth and distribution will be tax-free, it may prove to be a viable option. I'm just not sure if a non-legal guardian can open an account and contribute to it periodically...

Comment: She can open a 529 though?  Is there a specific reason for a coverdell?  Coverdells are much more limited compared to a 529

Comment: I have already max'ed out the 529 contribution...

Comment: The maximum 529 deposit this year is $65000. You can gift $13,000 to child in any year, but for a 529, may gift up to five years at once. A form 709, I believe, is required, but no tax due. Your spouse can do the same. The $2000 Coverdell offers no such flexibility, and is a tiny fraction of the deposits the 529 permits. Note - the $65000 lump sum means no further deposits from you for the next 4 years.

Comment: Not sure if this is a separate question - but can a 529 be used for a private school? Or can it only be earmarked for higher education?

Comment: 529 is higher education only. Coverdell can be used for private lower education. From your tax-deduction question, you seemed to believe the 529 limit was far lower than it is. What, exactly, is your goal? We seem to be dancing around the issue.

Comment: Basically, I want to evaluate my options should my 1 yr. old kid attend private school and wanted to maximize my investment options. Given that 529 can only be used for higher education, I can have my sister contribute $2000 per year (assuming the limit holds), invest it wisely, and have  a bit to offset the private school tuition...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in fact, if your MAGI is $220K or over as a couple, you are not able to open the account. Having a relative with lower income is a good way to set one up.

As MrChrister commented, the Coverdell is more limited, only $2000/yr, dropping to $500 if congress doesn't act. (limit was $2000 in 2012, to clarify) Funds must be disbursed by age 30 to the beneficiary. But - the investment options are as varied as any other investment accounts, with a 529, the choices for investment are quite limited. In a 529, unused funds can be used for a changed beneficiary within the same extended family, not so with Coverdell.

Comment: [IRS Pub 970](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p970/ch07.html) confirms this. Any person including the beneficiary with AGI less than $110K ($220K for joint) can contribute.

Comment: @amit_g - Thanks for the support! IRS pubs are the best references to these factual questions.